# Access functions of main page from innerhtml

Tags: html, angularjs, innerhtml

I have two html pages. In the main page, when a link is clicked, the url behind the link should be opened in a small inline window. After searching a lot I found that I could use Innerhtml to load the url into a small div (I also tested iframe and ajax but they did not work in chrome). 1. Is it possible to call a function defined in main page, inside the innerhtml? 2. Inside the main page and innerhtml page I have the same tabs and objects of same name, and one of the tabs is called map. when a button is clicked in innerhtml, I want a point to be added in the map of main page not the map of innerhtml itself. 
Here is a part of the code:

```
<script>
    function load_home(url) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" 
        data = "' + url + '" > < /object>';
    }

</script>
<ul class="list-group  gn-resultview">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="md in searchResults.records" gn-displayextent-onhover="" gn-zoomto-onclick gn-fix-mdlinks="">

        <div class="media-body">
            <div draggable id="content"> </div>

            <h4>
                <input gn-selection-md type="checkbox" ng-model="md['geonet:info'].selected" ng-change="change()" />
                <!-- Icon for types -->
                <a ng-href="#/metadata/{{md.getUuid()}}" onclick="load_home(this.href);return false;" title="{{md.title || md.defaultTitle}}">
                <i class="fa gn-icon-{{md.type[0]}}" title="{{md.type[0] | translate}}"/>
                {{(md.title || md.defaultTitle) | characters:80}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p class="text-justify" dd-text-collapse dd-text-collapse-max-length="350" dd-text-collapse-text="{{md.abstract || md.defaultAbstract}}"></p>
            <blockquote ng-if="md.getContacts().resource">{{::md.getContacts().resource}}</blockquote>
        </div>

        <div>
            <gn-links-btn></gn-links-btn>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it working with other browsers?

Comment: try ... document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<iframe 
         src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>'; (BE SURE your url is absolute)

Comment: @Roy So with this code am I able to link between innerhtml and main page? I edited the description to clarify the situation better, can you please take a look at my main problem again?

Comment: this code works in all browsers, my main problem is whether I am able to link between innerhtml and main page. @RameshRajendran

Comment: I think that you don't know what is innerHTML, right? the function literally create html code inside you page. so, you dont have two html, you have just one with a dinamic content. The functions in all the page are the same, and you can call it in any place.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for testing?

Comment: @Roy I actually called a function of main page from innerhtml, nothing happens. Sorry I can't create a jsfiddle, Because this is a small part of a huge system, it has many files related to each other, so it does not work if I just copy some parts into jsfiddle.

Comment: _I actually called a function of main page from innerhtml_ ...can you show me where?

Comment: @Roy Here is a system same as mine: http://geo.abds.is/geonetwork/srv/ger/catalog.search#/search. you see a map in the upper toolbar, and some links in a grid like structure at the botton, If you click on links they open. But I changed them so that they open in an inline small window. Now If some one clicks on several of these links on my page he will see several windows. some of them have a button called add to map. I want this button to add data to the map in main page. so all the data are in the same map not in maps in small windows.

Comment: click on the link in previous comment please. @Roy

Comment: Thanks @Roy I used parent.function() to call a function of main page from innerhtml.

Comment: Thanks to you @saminpayro! use window.parent.function() for crossbrowsing. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innerhtml page you can call a function of main page such as "test()" like this:
parent.test()

So as an example:
In the innerhtml url:

```
<script>
function test1()
{

 parent.test();
}
</script>
```

in the innehtml page:

```
 <button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"
                        data-ng-show="hasAction(mainType)"
                        onclick="test1()" >
```

Comment: To add an html page into a small div inside current page you can use: load-home(url) function as mentioned in the question, and to add the url inside an iframe you can use the answer mentioned in the comments of the question.